# hook_init() causes login problems

Tags: 7, hooks, users

I created a custom module which has the following `hook_init()` implementation.

```
function gate_init() {
  $curr_uri = check_plain(request_uri());
  if (strpos($curr_uri, 'admin') === FALSE) {
    if (strcmp($curr_uri, '/gate') != 0) {  
      if (!sess_read(GATE_SESSION_NAME)) {
        if (!isset($_COOKIE[GATE_COOKIE_NAME])) {
          drupal_goto('gate');
        }
        else {
          sess_write(GATE_SESSION_NAME, TRUE);
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      if (sess_read(GATE_SESSION_NAME) || isset($_COOKIE[GATE_COOKIE_NAME])) {
        if (!sess_read(GATE_SESSION_NAME)) {
          sess_write(GATE_SESSION_NAME, TRUE);
        }
        drupal_goto('/');
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

It's crazy, but this code causes login problems for authenticated users. I cannot login, I see no errors, I just cannot login if I provide correct username and password.

If I comment out these lines, I can login.

```
if (!sess_read(GATE_SESSION_NAME)) {
  if (!isset($_COOKIE[GATE_COOKIE_NAME])) {
    drupal_goto('gate');
  }
  else {
    sess_write(GATE_SESSION_NAME, TRUE);
  }
}
```

I check further and  `if (!sess_read(GATE_SESSION_NAME))` is the part causing login problems.   Could anybody give me an advice?

Comment: Hello @user1178, and welcome on _Drupal Answers_. It's not the cause of the issue you are having, but you should not use `check_plain()` on a value that you are comparing with a string; `check_plain()` should be used for values that you output, for example for a string you get as user input, and that could contain hHTML tags when you want to use as plain text. An example could be usernames like "<a>ntares" or "<b>art."

Comment: I am not if it is the reason for your problems, but try to use $_SESSION instead of sess_read/write() like you're doing currently, it is possible that this causes issues with Drupal's session handling.

Comment: Berdir gave the correct answer. sess_read/sess_write() are private Drupal functions. Don't use them. To store something in the session, use $_SESSION.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[sess_read()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--session.inc/function/sess_read/6) should not be used in a module, as that function is passed to [session_set_save_handler()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) from [_drupal_bootstrap()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/_drupal_bootstrap/6), which is the function that is called during Drupal bootstrap.
The purpose of the function is not to read values from the PHP session; if you need to do that, the you can just read the content from `$_SESSION[]`.
To notice that [session_start()](http://us.php.net/session_start) is called from Drupal during its bootstrap; that means that after a full bootstrap (or any bootstrap that goes past the `DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION` phase) a session is initialized, and `$_SESSION[]` can be used.